# Why am I suddenly getting "This site cannot be reached" in Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

Everything was working fine up to yesterday. VS2019. Net.Core 2.2 C#. Today I'm getting "This site cannot be reached" As far as I know I haven't changed any settings other than a routine Windows Update. I've read a fair few articles and nothing seems to work. Even a brand new web project with no changes has the same problem.

I get the same/similar no matter what browser I point at
I'm completely stuck. Does anyone have any ideas what it could be ?

[image]

Comment: Do you deploy you app on a locally installed IIS or do you use the virtual IIS from visual studio while debugging?

Comment: while debugging. start a brand new vs2019 core 2.2 app, start debugging and you get that error. i have restarted several times nothing seems to work :(

Comment: Check the requirements for HTTP2 support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#http2-support-1

Comment: It's annoying because I haven't changed anything. Yesterday I was coding and debugging and making good progress. Today I'm completely stalled

Comment: update: same issue in vs2017

Comment: update: it looks like it might be IIS. In vs2017 started a new project which runs fine. clone my other project from git doesn't run and gives the error. now any and all projects in vs2017 won't run and give the same error. and this is on a completely different machine.

Comment: update: i'm reading about this kestrel thing (thanks @DavidG) don't see how/why my project stopped working nor how it mysteriously kills IIS

Answer (score 0):

Wierd!

To fix this all I did was connect to a local SQL database (on my machine) as opposed to a remote one (external server) and then delete all the cookies related to the localhost website.

It looks like some cookies get left laying around (from the external SQL) that affect IIS somehow, for any and all sites using SSL. Monitoring cookies I get around 7 created when I use the external SQL and only 3 when using the local.

Anyway, I just deleted all those cookies (localhost) because IIS still refused to work. I don't know why and  I've just lost the entire day with this issue I may investigate another time but right now I need to crack on:(